# Months calculations inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, date, stored-procedures

I need to get a list of months that are not located inside the database.

***Example:***

Table **members**

```
ID | Member's code | Member since
1  |  555-12       |  2012-11-22
```

Table **membership**

```
ID |   Code  | Paid
1  |  555-12 | 2013-1-1
2  |  555-12 | 2013-3-12
3  |  555-12 | 2013-5-1
```

Let's say that today is : `2013-11-17`

I need to get output like this:

```
Member's code  |  Debt ( Months )
555-12         |    11-2012
555-12         |    12-2012
555-12         |     2-2013
555-12         |     4-2013
```

Is this possible to do with a SQL? Do I need to have a `stored procedure` where I will pass `Member's code`?

Comment: What do you mean by "not in the database"?  Is it possible to have a gap between two rows that is greater than one month?

Comment: do you also need to return 6-2013, 7-2013, ..., 11-2013? They have not been paid until now

Comment: Also, why is 11-2012 included?  You have a value for that month in your data.

Comment: @Andrew there shouldn't be that date. Sorry it was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to use a number table, that contains just numbers from 0 to 100 or more:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
  n INT
);

INSERT INTO numbers (n)
VALUES
(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15)...;
```

Then you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  m.ID,
  m.Code,
  DATE_FORMAT(m.Member_since + INTERVAL num.n MONTH, '%m-%Y') As Debt_Month_Year
FROM
  members m INNER JOIN numbers num
  ON TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, m.Member_since, LAST_DAY(CURDATE()))>=num.n
  LEFT JOIN membership ms
  ON
    m.Code = ms.Code
    AND
      LAST_DAY(ms.Paid)=LAST_DAY(m.Member_since + INTERVAL num.n MONTH)
WHERE
  ms.id IS NULL
  -- and if you wish, add the following line:
  AND m.Code = '555-12'
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2284/3).

Comment: How many numbers I need to have? Since I'll be having a lot of records displayed?

Comment: @user123_456 the numbers table is needed for the first join and is just the number of months... with 0..12 all members have to be members since 2012-11, with 0..120 you can cover 10 years... I have to explain it a little better...

Comment: hi, I would like to know if it is possible to use the same code but instead of the full dates I only need years.

Comment: please check out my new question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586007/years-calculations-inside-stored-procedure

Comment: @user123_456 i see that you already have an answer... let me know if you need something else :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select code,
left(since,7) as debt 
from user where code='555-12'

union all

select code,
left(date_add(paid, interval -1 MONTH),7) as debt 
from paid where code='555-12'
```

**Fiddle**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d988/1

Comment: this are the results that I get `543-12 2013-02` and
`543-12 2014-04`, I can only get the last and the first value...maybe there is something wrong with my mysql?

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that you will only have a consistent one month gap between the entries for each user, then I think timus's solution should work.

If not, I think you'll need to have some sort of date table to determine what values you don't have in the database.

Here's a SQL Fiddle demonstrating what I'm talking about. I intentionally removed one of the rows from your paid table to test skipping more than one month. Basically it gets the month from the member table (the first entry, I guess), and I union that to a second query getting the months that are not in the paid table.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69556f/2)

```
select
left (mbr_since,7) as MNTH
from
user
union

select
mnth
from
months
left outer join paid
on months.mnth = left(paid,7)
where
paid.code is null
```

The months table is just a row for each month (2013-01, 2013-02, etc). The second query joins to that, and then filters out rows where there is a match in the paid table.  Hopefully my explanation is making sense...

Comment: Yea, well the above example is working even if we don't have a gap of one month between

Comment: This handles skipped months, but if you like fthiella's solution, that's great too!