# Years calculations inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

My previous question, which is connected to this one, was already answered here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029149/months-calculations-inside-stored-procedure)

This query was working perfectly for me, however I need to do some changes.
Instead of showing every month as debt I would need to show only a year as debt.

For example:
I would need to check if there were any payments in the year, if there are none then I need to show that year in my table.
In my previous output I had something like this:

```
Member's code  |  Debt ( Months )        
555-12         |     2-2013        
555-12         |     4-2013
```

and now I would need this:

```
Member's code  |  Debt ( Years )
555-12         |     2012
```

This is what I've tried : [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2284/6)
In this example you can see that I have a year 2013 which shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query returns the years since the first membership with no matches:

```
select m.*, (year(Member_since) + n.n) as YearNotPaid
from members m join
     numbers n
     on year(Member_since) + n.n <= year(now()) left outer join
     membership ms
     on ms.code = m.code and
         year(Member_since) + n.n = year(ms.paid)
where ms.id is null;
```

You can include `AND m.Code = '555-12'` if you just want it for one member.